# How to tell journald to re-read its configuration?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

My question is simple: how do I tell journald to re-read its configuration file ***without rebooting***?

I've made some changes to `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and I'd like to see if they are correct and everything works as I expect.

I do not want to reboot.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To control running services with systemd, use the [`systemctl` utility](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). This utility is similar to the `service` utility provided by SysVinit and Upstart. Among others:

- `systemctl status systemd-journald` indicates whether the service is running and additional information if it is.
- `systemctl start systemd-journald` starts the service (systemd unit).
- `systemctl stop systemd-journald` stops the service.
- `systemctl restart systemd-journald` restarts the service.
- `systemctl reload systemd-journald` reloads the service's configuration if possible, but will not kill it (so no risk of a service interruption or of disrupting processing in progress, but the service may keep running with a stale configuration).
- **`systemctl force-reload systemd-journald`** reloads the service's configuration if possible, and if not restarts the service (so the service is guaranteed to use the current configuration, but this may interrupt something).
- `systemctl daemon-reload` reloads systemd's own configuration.

Comment: It's true. But you should update your `systemd` (use `v227`...). See https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2236

Comment: Atleeast on CentOS 7 the service name is systemd-journal**d**

Comment: `systemctl reload systemd-journald` gives me error `Failed to reload systemd-journald.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit systemd-journald.service.` on Centos 7

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379288/ for problems with this.

Answer (score 36):

`systemctl restart systemd-journald` does the trick.

I'm answering it myself as googling it does not return any useful page.

Comment: " If systemd-journald.service is restarted using systemctl restart or equivalent operation instead of a pair of separate systemctl stop and systemctl start commands (or equivalent operations), these stream connections are not terminated and survive the restart. It is thus safe to restart systemd-journald.service" https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html#Stream%20logging