# systemd unit with netcat and fifo

Tags: systemd, netcat

I have sequence of commands that work started by hand, but not with systemd on (HOST_TX):

HOST_**RX**:

```
nc -v -l -p 5006
```

Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 5006)

HOST_**TX**:

```
 /opt/sendtofifo.sh > /tmp/tofifo1                    # in a shell
 nc -v -w 3 HOST_RX 5006 < /tmp/tofifo1   # in a second shell
```

If I don't use the fifo, manually I'm able to send with:

```
/bin/bash -xc '/opt/sendtofifo.sh | /bin/nc -v -T lowdelay  HOST_RX 5006'
```

When HOST_RX stop listening both command exit clean instead systemd keep running the `/opt/sendtofifo.sh` ignoring the status of `nc`.

Tried to setup a systemd service as follow:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
RestartSec=2
ExecStart=/bin/bash -xc '/opt/sendtofifo.sh | /bin/nc -v -T lowdelay  HOST_RX 5006'
Restart=always
```

This works at first:

```
root@rx(boot:ro,root:rw):/home/pi# systemctl status  rx_rc.service
● rx_rc.service - RX RC Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rx_rc.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-09 14:34:52 CEST; 4s ago
 Main PID: 28649 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rx_rc.service
           ├─28649 /bin/bash -xc /opt/sendtofifo.sh  | /bin/nc -v -T lowdelay  10.11.10.11 5006; exit
           ├─28650 /opt/sendtofifo.sh 
           └─28651 /bin/nc -v -T lowdelay 10.11.10.11 5006
```

Now if HOST_RX close connection I get:

```
● rx_rc.service - RX RC Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rx_rc.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-09 14:34:52 CEST; 1min 11s ago
 Main PID: 28649 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rx_rc.service
           ├─28649 /bin/bash -xc /opt/sendtofifo.sh | /bin/nc -v -T lowdelay  10.11.10.11 5006; exit
           └─28650 /opt/sendtofifo.sh
```

Is there a way to restart the service if `nc` fails?

### responses to comments

**strace output for /opt/sendtofifo.sh process**

```
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=200000000}, NULL) = 0
write(1, "\0\0\f\0\4\200\0\0\30\0\0\0\264\277\0\0\271\315\6\0002\364\301\22\257\4 \0\315", 29) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1589, si_uid=0} ---
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=200000000}, NULL) = 0
```

Comment: You can check (with `strace -p 28650`) what the `/opt/sendtofifo.sh` process is doing.

Comment: thank you for advice, I get this output:
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=200000000}, NULL) = 0
write(1, "\0\0\f\0\4\200\0\0\30\0\0\0\264\277\0\0\271\315\6\0002\364\301\22\257\4 \0\315", 29) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1589, si_uid=0} ---
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=200000000}, NULL) = 0

Comment: That is difficult to read. You should add such information to the question (as I have done it for you now).

Comment: Sorry, Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious but wrong response is "But a `SIGPIPE` *will* cause your program to be terminated, because that's what `SIGPIPE` does, and a `Restart=always` setting will therefore cause it to restart.".

It's wrong because systemd defaults to executing services with the `SIGPIPE` signal ignored.  So the service process and its child(ren), which is a shell interpreting a script in this case, just ignore any `SIGPIPE`s and carry on.

Why does systemd do that?
It is because of `systemd-journald`.
In earlier versions of systemd when `systemd-journald` crashed or was otherwise terminated, all of the services whose standard outputs and standard errors were being sent to it would get a `SIGPIPE`.
If not ignored, this would cause pretty much every service on the system to be taken down by `systemd-journald`, an unfortunate state of affairs to say the least.
The systemd people hadn't learned the lesson from daemontools, where `svscan` ensured that it retained open file descriptors for the pipes between "main" service and "log" service, so that the "main" services never got spurious `SIGPIPE`s when the "log" services were restarted for any reason.

They eventually caught on, some years later, and systemd now holds open file descriptors to the pipes connecting services to `systemd-journald`, albeit that it does it in a rather roundabout fashion that involves letting processes inject file descriptors of their choosing into process #1.
Ignoring `SIGPIPE` as standard is no longer necessary because there's no need to paper over the original problem any more.

But the default for the `IgnoreSIGPIPE` setting in a service unit remains `yes`.

Change it to `no` in your service unit.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379531/5132

Comment: As a runit user (who knows about daemontools), the further reading is really interesting and enlightening.